# Elastic stack, not receiving data although follow default instructions

Tags: elasticsearch, elastic-stack

I've just installed ELK stack on our Unbuntu 16 server. I just followed default instructions (attached below), the OS shown closest to mine is Deb, so I picked that. However it seemed I can't receive data from logstash (last screenshot).

Am I missing something? Thanks

[image]

[image]
[image]

Comment: Can you please explain what is your architecture of ELK ? Example: Filebeat (shipping logs) >> Logstash (Filtering the logs, taking input from filebeat, output to ES) >> ES >> Kibana

Comment: @sourav19 Exactly like you said, I used Filebeat >> Logstash >> ES >> Kibana

Comment: Can you please check, when you run Filebeat, the harvester is running and backoff connection is established with logstash or not. There might be a case also when backoff connection from filebeat to logstash is established, but harvester is not running that time or there is no open files in harvester of filebeat. Please check running the logstash first, then filebeat and check the logs of filebeat.